# What does inherit means in CSS?

Tags: html, css, frontend

In the code below if I use:

```css
.override{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Then will it show the same color as it is showing now?

```css
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.override {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="pink">
  <p class="green">I'm classed "green", and I am green.</p>
  <p class="green override">I'm also classed "green" but `inherit` overrides this and causes me to inherit pink from my parent.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit

Comment: it works as intended unless you change the specificity weigth

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is the cascading as in Cascading style sheets (css).

Both the classes green and override have the same weight so the one that comes after the other wins.

In this snippet I’ve reversed the order and you can see that this time green wins.

```css
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
.override {
  background-color: inherit;
}
.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="pink">
  <p class="green">I'm classed "green", and I am green.</p>
  <p class="green override">I'm also classed "green" and I am green because I’ve overridden the class with ‘inherit’.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `inherit` keyword is used to apply the same value of a property from the parent element to its child element. This means that the child element will inherit the property value of the parent element, effectively making it the same as the parent.

Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit).

Comment: This does not provide an answer, because if you reverse the order of the style definitions the green selector wins.